# Python write of scraping data to csv file

Tags: python, csv

I wrote simple code which scrape data from website but i'm struggling to save all rows to csv file. Finished script save only one row - it's last occurance in loop.

```
def get_single_item_data(item_url):
    f= csv.writer(open("scrpe.csv", "wb"))  
    f.writerow(["Title", "Company", "Price_netto"]) 

    source_code = requests.get(item_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code.content, "html.parser")

for item_name in soup.find_all('div', attrs={"id" :'main-container'}):
    title = item_name.find('h1').text
    prodDesc_class = item_name.find('div', class_='productDesc')
    company = prodDesc_class.find('p').text
    company = company.strip()

    price_netto = item_name.find('div', class_="netto").text
    price_netto = price_netto.strip()


    #print title, company, ,price_netto

    f.writerow([title.encode("utf-8"), company, price_netto, ])
```

Important is to save data to concurrent columns

Comment: Fix your indentation but I am guessing there is only one div wit the id  `main-container` so you are writing exactly what you would expect, one item. What is the url?

Comment: can you post a sample output? I'm wondering if its there just not with the newline as you expect it.

Comment: @Will,  writerow would add a newline so that is definitely not the case.

Comment: Also why are you opening the file in binary mode?

Comment: just fishing cause the file is opened wb

Comment: @PadraicCunningham There sie only one div with id `main-container` but when i change from find_all to find the code dosen't work.

@Will My output is: `Title,Company,Price_netto
KLOCKI LEGO CITY HELIKOPTER BADACZY 60093,Technic,159.00` but i should have many many rows

When i added f.close() I'm getting: `AttributeError: '_csv.writer' object has no attribute 'close' `

Comment: Yes, what would you expect to happen when you have just a single element? Also you don't close the writer, you close the file or just use with to open your files and it will take care of closing them.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham how to close this type of writing csv? f.close() doesn't work. When the csv file will be closed all rows will be wrote to this file?

Comment: You need not worry about it, that is not the problem you are facing. Add a link to the site you are scraping if possible.

Comment: @Merix. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31828279/why-does-my-my-text-file-keep-overwriting-the-data-on-it/31828325#31828325

Answer (score 1):

@PadraicCunningham This is my whole script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

url_klocki = "http://selgros24.pl/Dla-dzieci/Zabawki/Klocki-pc1121.html"
r = requests.get(url_klocki)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

def main_spider(max_page):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_page:
        url = "http://selgros24.pl/Dla-dzieci/Zabawki/Klocki-pc1121.html"
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code.content, "html.parser")

        for link in soup.find_all('article', class_='small-product'):
            url = "http://www.selgros24.pl"
            a = link.findAll('a')[0].get('href')
            href = url + a
            #print href

            get_single_item_data(href)

        page +=1

def get_single_item_data(item_url):
    f= csv.writer(open("scrpe.csv", "wb"))   
    f.writerow(["Title", "Comapny", "Price_netto"]) 

    source_code = requests.get(item_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code.content, "html.parser")

    for item_name in soup.find_all('div', attrs={"id" :'main-container'}):
        title = item_name.find('h1').text
        prodDesc_class = item_name.find('div', class_='productDesc')
        company = prodDesc_class.find('p').text
        company = company.strip()

        price_netto = item_name.find('div', class_="netto").text
        price_netto = price_netto.strip()


        print title, company, price_netto

        f.writerow([title.encode("utf-8"), company, price_netto])


main_spider(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are opening the output file in `get_single_item_data`, and it is getting closed when that function returns and `f` goes out of scope.
You want to pass an open file in to `get_single_item_data` so multiple rows will be written.