# Trying to do a code but it does something different

Tags: python

So, I did this python program and whenever I run it it says in the file "This is an update" and only one of the quotes I entered. Any help? Program below.

```
file_name = "my_quote.txt"
new_file = open(file_name, "w")
new_file.close()

def update_file(file_name,quote):
    new_file = open(file_name, "w")
    new_file.write("This is an update\n")
    new_file.write(quote)
    new_file.write("\n\n")
    new_file.close()

for index in range(1,3):
    quote = input("Enter your favorite quote:")
    update_file(file_name, quote)

new_file = open(file_name, "r")
print(new_file.read())

new_file.close()
```

Comment: also prefer using with open construct

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my my text file keep overwriting the data on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31828279/why-does-my-my-text-file-keep-overwriting-the-data-on-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing over the current file as you are not opening the file in append mode.
If you change the open command to this instead:

```
file.open(file_path, 'a')
```

You will append the text instead of writing over the file.

Answer (score 3):

You're opening your file in `w` mode, which overwrites the file.

Use `a` for append mode, which, well, appends new content at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you re-open a file, and use `write` it removes all content previously in the file and overwrites it. And since every time you call `update_file` you are re-opening it and `write`ing to it, only the last piece of info written in the last `open` will be kept (as all previous data was overwritten.

I think you want to use `append` mode when writing data to the file. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) for a list of all the modes, and their function.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you! Adding append seems to have fixed the problem!

Comment: No problem! If an answer helped be sure to accept one so the question can be closed.