# Adding text at the beginning of multiple txt files into a folder. Problem of overwriting the text inside

Tags: python, python-3.x

im trying to add the same text at the beggining of all the txt files that are in a folder.

With this code i can do it, but there is a problem, i dont know why it overwrite part of the text that is at the beginning of each txt file.

```
output_dir = "output"

if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
    os.makedirs(output_dir)

for f in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    with open(f, 'r', encoding="utf8") as inputfile:
        with open('%s/%s' % (output_dir, ntpath.basename(f)), 'w', encoding="utf8") as outputfile:
            for line in inputfile:
                outputfile.write(line.replace(line,"more_text"+line+"text_that_is_overwrited"))
            outputfile.seek(0,io.SEEK_SET)
            outputfile.write('text_that_overwrite')
            outputfile.seek(0, io.SEEK_END)
            outputfile.write("more_text")
```

The content of txt files that im trying to edit start with this:

**here 4 spaces** text_line_1

**here 4 spaces** text_line_2

The result is:

- On file1.txt: text_that_overwrite**ited**
- On file1.txt: text_that_overwrite**rited**

Comment: You write all the lines, then `seek` to the start and overwrite the first line... Why not just write the first extra line you want, then write all other lines in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

Your mental model of how writing a file works seems to be at odds with what's actually happening here.

If you `seek` back to the beginning of the file, you will start overwriting *all* of the file. There is no such thing as writing into the middle of a file. A file - at the level of abstraction where you have `open` and `write` calls - is just a stream; seeking back to the beginning of the stream (or generally, seeking to a specific position in the stream) and writing replaces everything which was at that place in the stream before.

Granted, there is a lower level where you could actually write new bytes into a block on the disk whilst that block still remains the storage for a file which can then be read as a stream. With most modern file systems, the only way to make this work is to replace that block with exactly the same amount of data, which is very rarely feasible. In other words, you can't replace a block containing 1024 bytes with data which isn't also exactly 1024 bytes. This is so marginally useful that it's simply not an operation which is exposed to the higher level of the file system.

With that out of the way, the proper way to "replace lines" is to not write those lines at all. Instead, write the replacement, followed by whichever lines were in the original file.

It's not clear from your question what exactly you want overwritten, so this is just a sketch with some guesses around that part.

```py
output_dir = "output"

# prefer exist_ok=True over if not os.path.exists()
os.makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)

for f in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    # use a single with statement
    # prefer os.path.basename over ntpath.basename; use os.path.join
    with    open(f, 'r', encoding="utf8") as inputfile, \
            open(os.path.join(output_dir, os.path.basename(f)), 'w', encoding="utf8") as outputfile:
        for idx, line in enumerate(inputfile):
            if idx == 0:
                outputfile.write("more text")
                outputfile.write(line.rstrip('\n'))
                outputfile.write("text that is overwritten\n")
                continue
            # else:
            outputfile.write(line)
        outputfile.write("more_text\n")
```

Given an input file like

```
here is some text
here is some more text
```

this will create an output file like

```
more texthere is some texttext that is overwritten
here is some more text
more_text
```

where the first line is a modified version of the original first line, and a new line is appended after the original file's contents.

Answer (score -1):

I found this elsewhere on StackOverflow. [Why does my text file keep overwriting the data on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31828279/why-does-my-text-file-keep-overwriting-the-data-on-it)

Essentially, the `w` mode is meant to overwrite text.

Also, you seem to be writing a sitemap manually. If you are using a web framework like Flask or Django, they have plugin or built-in support for auto-generated sitemaps — you should use that instead. Alternatively, you could create an XML template for the sitemap using Jinja or DTL. Templates are not just for HTML files.

Comment: This is a red herring. The OP's code creates a new file; of course, they should use `w` mode for that. The problem is that they `seek` back to the beginning for unclear reasons.

Comment: OP was asking why the text in their file was being overwritten. That is what `w` does by design. I did not say they should use a different mode because are trying to both overwrite text and append text to the beginning of the file with the same object.